# How to scan for minecraft lan games via terminal

Tags: lan, nmap, minecraft

I'm trying to figure out how to scan for Minecraft lan games on a local network. When I open up the game itself, the scan happens very quickly and almost immediately returns a list of local ip's and their respective ports. However, I don't want to keep the game open in the background just to check for active ports, I'd like to do it with a script.

I tried to use **nmap** to scan for specific ports, but as far as I can tell, Minecraft games on lan have no set port range. It's too slow to scan every ip on the network on the tens of thousands ports that Minecraft can use.

The closest thing I've found to an answer is on this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1117756/how-does-minecraft-find-lan-servers), although I'm not sure how applicable it is based on the time period (4 years ago, and since then the game has gone over significant development) and the fact that I do not have to worry about multiple switches.

Also on my quest for research, I looked at something about broadcast packets. However, I'm not sure where to begin with this, or if this can even be used to work for my goals.

So my overall goal is to use (Linux) terminal to search for Minecraft games on my local network (lan). Really, any pointers on how to achieve this would be great, or if someone could just point me in the right direction. At least I now know that it is infeasible to use nmap.

Thanks! Let me know if I need to edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I used Wireshark and found that lan games send a UDP packet to the multicast 224.0.2.60:4445 while they're running. I wrote a simple bash script to listen for these packets with Wireshark, then trigger a Dunst notification when found. The data contains the name of the user, world, and tcp port, which I extracted with ack. It does use significantly less ram than just leaving Minecraft open, and I get the benefit of notifications.

Comment: Is this for the Java or Bedrock edition (or both)?